# Linux RDP to Windows 2012 r2 Shadow Session

Tags: linux, remote-desktop

I need to connect to a shadow session in Windows 2012 r2.

From a Windows client it's easy, just run:

```
mstsc /v:SERVERNAME /shadow:SESSIONID /control
```

But how can I do this from a Linux PC (with Remmina or other RDP Client)?